# Salesforce child to parent relationship query returns null for parent object

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created lookup-relationship for standard object Account and custom object Child__c in salesforce. Using following query when I tries to fetch Account's i.e parent object field, query assist returns.

Queries are:

```
1. Select id, Account__r.Active__c from Child__c 
2. Select id, Account__r.Type from Child__c
```

[image]

Can anybody assist me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It means that those record are linked to no Account. You could verify adding a WHERE clause to the query: `SELECT Id, Account__r.Active__c from Child__c WHERE Account__c != null`. This query should return 0 record.
You have to update those records setting the lookup field `Account__c` with a valid id.
Once `Account__c` holds a reference to an Account, if you rerun that query and you'll see the parent fields.

By the way, when you create a new custom field, even if you add a default value (you can't for a lookup field), it will be `null` for the pre-existing records.